# Get all options from WordPress options table

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, plugins

Is there a way to get all of the options that are currently being store in the options table for my Wordpress plugin?

```
foreach ($options as $slug => $values) {
    var_dump($slug);
}
```

I have that but it only returns one single option and I need all of them to iterate over the $slug variable

Answer (score 2):

Please find the code below :

```
$options = wp_load_alloptions();
foreach ($options as $slug => $values) {
    var_dump($slug);
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

By using [wp_load_alloptions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_load_alloptions) You can have all the options of wp-option table.

```
$all_options = wp_load_alloptions();
$my_options  = array();

foreach ( $all_options as $name => $value ) {
    var_dump($name);
    var_dump($value);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: what is the '_transient' string about?

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-manage-and-delete-transients-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to find an option or do a one off change, there is actually a hidden page WordPress has that will let you edit these options. It's located at `example.com/wp-admin/options.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wp_load_all_options](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_load_alloptions) WordPress function.

> Retrieve all autoload options or all options, if no autoloaded ones exist. This function caches its results. It will pull the autoload options by default unless that fails, in which case it will return all options.